# How to track a process time and disk usage of that particular process in Unix?

Tags: unix, tcsh

I'm trying to compile and run simulations using tcsh shell in unix. How can i track time when the compilation has started and stopped, and what is the disk usage?

Comment: Use `time yourcommand` to get runtime information. For  IO information, see https://serverfault.com/questions/169676/howto-check-disk-i-o-utilisation-per-process

Answer (score 0):

Using `time` you can track the internal CPU time spent on a process.  You also can view what `top` (or similar tools like `ps`) displays for your process.  Typically the CPU minutes spent on that process are shown.  You can also use `date` before and after the process, maybe with option `+%s` to show the date as seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z to allow easy arithmetic with it (difference).  Keep in mind that CPU time can be larger (more than one CPU used) or smaller (CPU also working on other tasks) than real time.  Using `date` will always show real time.  `time` will try to show both.

Disk usage, however, is more complex.  By design, files are not dedicated to a specific process.  You can, however, run `df` before and after the process and compare the two values.  You cannot be sure that the difference was *created* by the process, but if you do several runs, that might help.  Also you can use `du` to find out how much storage size is used *in a particular path*.  This only works if you happen to know (or have a good guess) where the process stores its results in files.  In your case, this might be the best way to go as you talk about a compilation job.

You can also have a look at the `/proc/<PID>/fd/` directory to see the currently held open file descriptors of a running process.